# Buffering and processing real-time multicast data with .NET

Tags: udp, buffer, real-time, multicast, mpeg2-ts

I am trying to parse MPEG2-TS data being received over multicast. The problem is that the receiving method sometimes skips packets - and I believe this is heavily dependent on what extra processing is done between successive Receive() methods [According to the research I did, if the CPU is not on the Receive() method, packets will be lost, so buffering would be the fastest option not to process immediately, and leave this to be done from another thread ... am I right?].

I am currently using a queue to save the received datagrams for later processing from another thread by using the dequeue method. I have also switched to using a blocking multicast receiver initialised on a new thread, instead of an asynchronous receiver to ensure there are no delays delegating from one thread to another [i.e. for example, when using OnReceiveFrom() method].

The code for the Multicast receiver is given below:

```
class Multicast
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The possible Operating Modes allowed for this Multicast Class File
    /// </summary>
    public enum OperationMode
    {
        Client,
        Server
    };

    private IPAddress ipAddress;
    private int portNumber;
    private int interfaceIndex;
    private Socket socket;
    private EndPoint sourceOrDestination;
    private byte[] Data;
    private OperationMode operationMode;

    public Queue<byte[]> q = new Queue<byte[]>();

    public Multicast(string ipAddress, int portNumber, int interfaceIndex, OperationMode operationMode)
    {
        if (!IPAddress.TryParse(ipAddress, out this.ipAddress))
        {
            throw new Exception("Incorrect Argument Data. Unable to parse IP Address!");
        }
        this.portNumber = portNumber;
        this.interfaceIndex = interfaceIndex;
        this.operationMode = operationMode;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, portNumber); // Local IP and Port (if more than one NIC interface is available, this command must be altered!

        //socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp,SocketOptionName.Broadcast,true);
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.NoDelay, 1);
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1); // Allow for loopback testing 
        socket.Bind(localEndPoint); // Extremly important to bind the Socket before joining multicast groups 
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, Properties.Settings.Default.Network_MulticastTTL); // Set TTL (e.g.: 1 for one router hop)
        try
        {
            socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(ipAddress, interfaceIndex)); // Join Multicast
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReceiveBuffer, Properties.Settings.Default.Network_FramePayloadSize);
        socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.SendBuffer, Properties.Settings.Default.Network_FramePayloadSize);
        //socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Udp, SocketOptionName.DontFragment, 1);
        socket.DontFragment = true;



        while (true)
        {
            Data = new byte[socket.ReceiveBufferSize];
            socket.Receive(Data);

            q.Enqueue(Data);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This function is used to stop the socket from sending/receiving further data. The socket is therefore closed.
    /// </summary>
    public void Stop()
    {
        socket.Close();
    }
}
```

Even literally dumping all the datagrams received to a .ts file, one may notice pixellation and skips in audio while playing it in VLC. In reality, the packets are received successfully by the NIC card since wireshark displays them all, and in order, and the stream can be played without problems in VLC (when opening the stream directly).

What would you recommend to get an improvement in the result?

Comment: You do some unnecessary work with settings, but that's not critical. What is the value of `Properties.Settings.Default.Network_FramePayloadSize`? That might restrict you to a single packet buffered in-kernel.

Comment: It's 1316 bytes, the exact size for 7 transport packets in a single frame (same as shown in Wireshark) ... when I tried to enlarged this, the other bytes were simply set to 0. Is it possible that the following extended bytes are not 0 in cases where more than one packet are inside this low-level buffer?

Answer (score 3):

Just as I thought you are restricting your socket receive buffer to about a single datagram. The value given to [`SetSocketOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1011kecd.aspx) for [`ReceiveBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketoptionname.aspx) should be larger, so the kernel has enough space to buffer several input datagrams for you while your app is not immediately reading from the socket (say processing your current input). Multiply your current receive buffer size value by say a hundred.

Then what you are saying in reply comment about bytes being zero does not make much sense. Looking at your code - you are not taking return value of [`Receive()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff.aspx) (i.e. the actual number of bytes received) into account, instead assuming you get `ReceiveBufferSize` bytes every time.